# Difference between Google Correlate and Google Trends time serie for the same keyword

Tags: google-trends

The time series for a given keyword (e.g `stackoverflow`) will differ, for **the same area** and the **same time period**, whether it is extracted from *Google Correlate* or *Google Trends*.

When I say differ I mean that the correlation between the two series is not one (I am not talking about normalization difference).

Why is that ?